# Spark is Giving a long and repeated timeout error when I increase my data size

Tags: python, cassandra, apache-spark, cluster-computing, pyspark

I am using a Cassandra database to house some data and I have written a script to pull some set amount of data from it and put it into a pandas data frame. I am then converting certain columns of this data to a spark RDD so that I can find meaningful information.

When I give it above a certain amount of data it doesn't crash but rather repeatedly sends this error I am quite new to python, spark and programming in general so I really can't say much else about it.

Here is the error:

```
Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1176983551]] had already been terminated.
    at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEndpointRef.ask(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    ... 14 more
15/07/28 11:39:53 WARN AkkaRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@544f81f3,BlockManagerId(driver, localhost, 41320))] in 1 attempts
akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Recipient[Actor[akka://sparkDriver/user/HeartbeatReceiver#-1176983551]] had already been terminated.
    at akka.pattern.AskableActorRef$.ask$extension(AskSupport.scala:132)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEndpointRef.ask(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.askWithRetry(RpcEndpointRef.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:444)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:464)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The code executed up until after the normal information retrieval step from Cassandra so I think the issue is with spark but I'm not sure

Comment: did you find a  solution for this problem?

Comment: hi, have you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: Try setting [configuration item](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)  `spark.rpc.askTimeout` or `spark.network.timeout` (which alters a couple of timeouts with one setting) higher.